# Laravel Blade Request method

Tags: php, laravel, post, httprequest, laravel-blade

Recently I started learning Laravel by following the Laravel From Scratch cast(https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch).

Right now I'm trying to add additional functionality to the registration form(starting with error feedback) and I already ran into a problem.

Is there a (native) way to check wether the form has been submitted or not?
I tried to use:

```
{{ Request::method() }}
```

But even after pressing Register on the default scaffold generated by running the command `php artisan make:auth` it returns **GET** while the action of the form is **POST** and it triggers a route with a **POST Request** type.

The reason for all of this is that I want to add a CSS class to a element based on the following requirements.

```
if form is submitted
   if $errors->has('name') //is there an error for name(example)
      add 'has-error' class
   else
      add 'has-success' class
   endif
endif
```

Does anybody know a solution for it?

Comment: I've already tried checking for the flashed to the session values(example: old('name')) but that doesn't work since they would not exist if the fields are empty when submitting the form.

Comment: Have you tried validating the request response by creating helper function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to achieve this:

```
if( old('name') ){ // name has been submitted
  if( $errors->first('name') ){ // there is at least an error on it
    // add error class
  }else{ // has been submitted without errors
    // add valid class
  }
}
```

That in a input field is something like this:

```
<input name="name" class="validate{{ old('name') ? ( $errors->first('name') ? ' invalid'  : ' valid') : '' }}" type="text" value="{{ old('name') }}">
```

Comment: the problem with old is once you call it once, it is gone. you can't check if it is set twice.

Answer (score 0):

Rick,

You can validate you should have a look at the validate function in Laravel. You can validate the input you sent in and when there are errors send them back into your view.

For examples look at the url: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Hope this helps.

Comment: The validation part works fine, it's the part where I have to check in the view wether the form has been submitted before or not.

Comment: Ah ok! I think the method Allesandro is reffering to is the method you want to use!